# What determines whether or not a PDF may be previewed in Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, pdf

I have multiple PDFs stored in Google Docs, some quite lengthy (over 1k pages). Some of them allow preview, others do not. What are the requirements for preview? Must the PDF be created by a certain Acrobat version or newer?

Comment: Can you confirm the 25 MB threshold limit?

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive will preview a file when the respective file size is lower or equal to 25 MB.

See reference: [file size](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2423485&topic=2375192&ctx=topic)